# What should i do to complete Ubuntu upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade

I have been trying to upgrade from ubuntu 13.04 to latest avaiable version, but i keep getting `unsolvable problem` error message and update process terminates after rolling back.

Here is my log file (apt.log from `/var/log/dist-upgrade`): http://paste.ubuntu.com/6568967/.

It has a bunch of "holding back" messages related to certain packages (namely `libgjs0d:i386`, `gnome-shell:i386` to give an example). What should i do for upgrade to go on through?

Should i just go and purge them? What if a chunk of the system depends of them (which as i fear may be the case)?

P.s.

Output of `apt-get check`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

Contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6570863/

Output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:        13.04
Codename:       raring
```

Comment: Can you edit the questions and add the output of `sudo apt-get check` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `lsb_release -a`

Comment: Did you up-date your pinning info in /etc/apt/preferences.d ?

Comment: Braiam: added what you said to add
virtualxtc: no; how do i do that? (and why?)

Answer (score 0):

They were Hold back because their dependencies were changed in new distribution.

Certain new dependencies were added to or removed from the same package in new version. So if the new dependencies have their own dependencies that are not going to be installed, the upgrading is held back.

Try with following :

```
sudo aptitude full-upgrade
```

**If this not solve** the problem :

Then you need to copy the package names that were held back and their dependencies.

Example :

```
Broken [PACKAGE 1M] Depends on [PACKAGE 1D] [VERSION D] 
  Considering [PACKAGE 1D] [VERSION D]  a solution to [PACKAGE 1D] [VERSION M] 
  Holding Back [PACKAGE 1M] rather than change [PACKAGE 1D] [VERSION D]
```

*`M`-main `D`-dependent*

Here you need to copy `[PACKAGE 1M]` and `[PACKAGE 1D]`

Then run :

```
sudo apt-get install [PACKAGE 1M] [PACKAGE 1D] [PACKAGE 2M] [PACKAGE 2D] ........
```